# Crash from [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]] objectForKey:@"AppleLocale"][0];

Tags: crash, nsuserdefaults

my code is crashing on startup when i call this code

[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]] objectForKey:@"AppleLocale"][0];

The app is now live in production and when a user tries to upgrade, even though i have taken out this code it crashes before main. Is there any way to repair this or reset NSUserDefaults before main?

any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `defaults` command to modify preferences.

`defaults delete <domain>` will delete defaults (preferences) for the domain (e.g. The value of `CFBundleIdentifier` in `Info.plist`).

Also try deleting or renaming the application preferences file in `~/Library/Preferences`. But note that the user defaults system caches some data in memory, so incorrect application data is still retained even after the preferences file is deleted.